# unclear Ruby(Rails) execution flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-activerecord

I am having trouble seeing why the program execution seems to go back to the beginning of a method. This is my method:

[image]

All it does is save a `Doc` to the database if it is valid (That is, I have this line in the `Doc` model: `validates :docname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: true }`).
If it is not, the method returns.

Now, each `Doc` has many `Snippets`, with titles preformatted to be preceded with a "#" character. I did not put any validations on this.

My problem is this:[image]

As can be seen here, the `Doc` first passes validation, execution reaches the for loop, a `Snippet` is saved, and then the execution suddenly goes back to the top, then the same `Doc` now fails validation and the method returns.

Any ideas what I might have done wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling the `parse` method? That code is likely calling it twice for the same `result`.

Comment: but even if i'm accidentally calling it twice, why does it not continue execution the first time i called it? it did not even exit the for loop

Comment: There are no magic in programming. If you encounter method call during method call it's called recursion. Check if your method indirectly (or directly) calls itself. May be some gems you are using defined method `parse` on this class and use it for internal purposes... In short - just debug it and find place where actual call occurs! P.S. Generally wrong is not using ruby in ruby-way: 1. `save` performs validation and return false, if it fails. You don't need call `valid?` before `save`. 2. use `each` (or `each_with_index` if you need indices) method on `Array` instead of `for ... in`.

Comment: It would also help if you copy and paste more of the actual code rather than a screen shot. Indent the code an extra 4  spaces and it will get syntax coloring from SO.